# Web scraping from html code of a database using python

Tags: python, html, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to python and am learning things slowly. I have earlier performed API calls from databases to extract infromation. However, I was dealing with a particular Indian database. The html script seems confusing to extract the particular infromation I am looking for. Basically, I have a list of herb name links as input which looks like this(only the ID changes):

> 

```
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/3315/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f8
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/2133/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f9
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/845/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f10
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/363/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f11
```

When I open each of this, I want to extract the "Distribution" detail for these herb links from the webpage. That's all.  But, in the html script, I cant figure which header has the detail. I tried a lot before coming here. Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```py
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
import os
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint

user_home = os.path.expanduser('~')
OUTPUT_DIR = os.path.join(user_home, 'vk_frlht')
Path(OUTPUT_DIR).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

herb_url = 'http://envis.frlht.org/bot_search'
response = requests.get(herb_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
token = soup.find('Type Botanical Name', {'type': 'hidden', 'name': 'token'})
herb_query_url = 'http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/3315/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f8'

response = requests.get('http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/3315/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f8')

#optional code for many links at once

with open(Path, 'r') as f:
    frlhtinput = f.readlines()
    frlht = [x[:-1] for x in frlhtinput]

    for line in frlht:
        out = requests.get(f'http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/{line}')
#end of the optional code

herb_query_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
text = herb_query_soup.find('div', {'id': 'result-details'})
pprint(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how this page looks after scrapping:

[image]

Loading sign in the middle means that content can be loaded only after JavaScript code executes. Meaning someone protected this content with JS code. You have to use Selenium browser instead of BS4.

See tutorial [here](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

plant_ids = ["3315", "2133", "845", "363"]
results = []
for plant_id in plant_ids:
    herb_query_url = f"http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/{plant_id}/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f8"
    headers = {
        "Referer": herb_query_url,
    }
    response = requests.get(
        f"http://envis.frlht.org/bot_search/plantdetails/plantid/{plant_id}/nocache/0.7763327765552295/referredfrom/extplantdetails",
        headers=headers,
    )
    herb_query_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    result = herb_query_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "initbriefdescription"})
    for r in result:
        result_dict = {r.text.split(":", 1)[0].strip(): r.text.split(":", 1)[1].strip()}
        results.append(result_dict)
pprint(results)
```

Comment: Thanks, I can use for loop for plant ids here, right? I have a list of 1000+ herb entries for which I need this information, so. Also, one more thing, this question will be a repetition, I apologize in advance.  How do I get this output in table format? The headings are similar, so how do I go about this? Is it possible? Please help

Comment: import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

Comment: Is the above code correct to insert at the end of the script? I should be removing NaN to get them in 1 line I think....can you help with this

Comment: I modified to input list of ids one by one using for loop. But I am getting an error in it. This is the for loop. I did not change anything else. `Path = 'IDs.txt'
with open(Path, 'r') as f:
    idsinput = f.readlines()
    ids = [x[:-1] for x in idsinput]
    #print(ids)
    
results = []

for plant_id in ids:` The error is as follows. `---> 29         result_dict = {r.text.split(":", 1)[0].strip(): r.text.split(":", 1)[1].strip()}
     30         results.append(result_dict)
     31 pprint(results)

IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0):

The information is obtained from another URL based on the URLs you have. First you need to construct the required URL (which was found looking at the browser) and requesting that.

This information could be written to a CSV file as follows. It assumes you have a text file `IDs.txt` as follows:

```
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/3315/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f8
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/2133/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f9
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/845/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f10
http://envis.frlht.org/plantdetails/363/fd01bd598f0869d65fe5a2861845f9f11
```

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


fieldnames = ["ID", "Accepted Name", "Family", "Used in", "Distribution"]

with open('IDs.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for line in f_input:
        url = line.strip()  # Remove newline
        print(url)
        url_split = url.split('/')
        url_details = f"http://envis.frlht.org/bot_search/plantdetails/plantid/{url_split[4]}/nocache/{url_split[5]}/referredfrom/extplantdetails"
        
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
            'Referer' : url,
        }
        
        req = requests.get(url_details, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
        row = {field : '' for field in fieldnames}      # default values
        row['ID'] = url_split[4]
            
        for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="initbriefdescription"):
            entry, value = div.get_text(strip=True).split(":" ,1)
            row[entry] = value

        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Giving an output starting:

```
ID,Accepted Name,Family,Used in,Distribution
3315,Amaranthus hybridusL. subsp.cruentusvar.paniculatusTHELL.,AMARANTHACEAE,"Ayurveda, Siddha, Folk","This species is globally distributed in Africa, Asia and India. It is said to be cultivated as a leafy vegetable in Maharashtra, Karnataka (Coorg) and on the Nilgiri hills of Tamil Nadu. It is also found as an escape."
2133,Triticum aestivumL.,POACEAE,"Ayurveda, Siddha, Unani, Folk, Chinese, Modern",
845,Dolichos biflorusL.,FABACEAE,"Ayurveda, Siddha, Unani, Folk, Sowa Rigpa","This species is native to India, globally distributed in the Paleotropics. Within India, it occurs all over up to an altitude of 1500 m. It is an important pulse crop particularly in Madras, Mysore, Bombay and Hyderabad."
363,Brassica oleraceaL.,BRASSICACEAE,"Ayurveda, Siddha",
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly. Just one small doubt along with this. How do I get this in table format? As I have a list of 1000+ herb entries for which I need this information. The headings are similar, so how do I go about this? Sorry about the very silly questions. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: What kind of table format? Do you mean CSV output, Pandas dataframe etc?  Not all IDs have a distribution entry.

Comment: Yes, I wanted a CSV output. Yes, some of them don't have it, in that case it will be an empty cell right in CSV ?

Comment: The answer shows how a CSV file can be created. Yes, by default it adds an empty cell

Comment: Hello sir, Im very sorry to bother you again. I tried the code, but it is not saving properly in the csv file. It gives an I/O value error saying file is closed. And the output was not showing in table format as you got it. Can you please see if I have done anything wrong in the code

Comment: I am re-inserting the code as an answer, please take a look. The code ran and I got an output. But it has only one row, where all the details are in single cell. Looks like the dict file is copied into a single cell. Can you please take a look and tell if I am missing something here

Comment: I have retested this solution and it appears to work perfectly, giving the output as shown. Your code has broken how the data is written, it only outputs the last row. Rather than writing a row at a time, you appear to try and store it before writing at the end, but you are not storing a list, just one row. I would not recommend that approach, if your code failed mid-way, nothing would be written.

Comment: Make sure you keep the exact same indenting or it will not work. The file will be automatically closed outside the `with` block

Comment: It gives me an index error when I run the above code as it is.  Please see the line with the error:      url_details = f"http://envis.frlht.org/bot_search/plantdetails/plantid/{url_split[4]}/nocache/{url_split[5]}/referredfrom/extplantdetails"
     17 
     18         headers = {

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It means the URL has a different format to your example

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


fieldnames = ["ID", "Accepted Name", "Family", "Used in", "Distribution"]

with open('IDs.txt') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
csv_output.writeheader()

for line in f_input:
    url = line.strip()  # Remove newline
    print(url)
    url_split = url.split('/')
    url_details = f"http://envis.frlht.org/bot_search/plantdetails/plantid/{url_split[4]}/nocache/{url_split[5]}/referredfrom/extplantdetails"
    
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer' : url,
    }
    
    req = requests.get(url_details, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
    row = {field : '' for field in fieldnames}      # default values
    row['ID'] = url_split[4]
    
    result = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "initbriefdescription"})
    for r in result:
        result_dict = r.get_text(strip=True).split(":" ,1)
        results.append(result_dict)
        
        row[entry] = results
        print(row)

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames, extrasaction='ignore')
    csv_output.writeheader()
    csv_output.writerow(row)
```